# Reading many single files and creating numbered (? or indexed) variable

Tags: import, data-structures

I tried many different approaches, but I could not solve the following problems, I appreciate your help:
What is the best way to read many data files? I mean we have `file1.dat, file2.dat, file3.dat …`. and I would like to put them in a loop and by using the readlist, import the data, something like what we do in C and `sprintf` or in bash scripting. I have seen that there is a package which can handle `sprintf` functionality in Mathematica, but I am looking for simpler solution something like this: (I just used `$` sign to show what I mean, like bash)

```
Do[d$i = ReadList["/path/file$i.dat", Number, RecordLists -> True], {i, 1, 5}]
```

Can I create a variable like `d$i` inside the above loop over i? which creates `d1, d2, …`, and so on, after running the loop?

How can I remove the curly braces from `Mean` output? I have a single list and the Flatten does not remove the curly braces.

```
tt = {1, 2, 3, 4, ...} 
Flatten[Mean[tt]] = {1234.1234}
```

Comment: How are you getting list out of `Mean`? It normally doesn't return a list, but a number.

Comment: Just using the `Mean` command for the single list which is created by `ReadList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

First create the `Symbols` for all the variables you need:

```
 dd =  Symbol /@ ("d" <> ToString[#]& /@ Range[5])

 ff = "file" <> ToString[#] <> ".dat" & /@ Range[5]
```

Now read in the file:

```
Evaluate[dd] = ReadList[#,  Number, RecordLists -> True] & /@ ff;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @RunnyKine. I have tried your  method, but I got this error message: `SetDirectory["/home/arash/Desktop/test"];`

`dd = Symbol /@ ("d" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[9]);`

`ff = "file" <> ToString[#] <> ".dat" & /@ Range[9];`

`Evaluate[dd] = 
  ReadList["/home/arash/Desktop/test/" <> #, Number, 
     RecordLists -> True] & /@ ff;`

`Set::wrsym: Symbol $Failed is Protected. >>`

Comment: Since you've `SetDirectory` to that folder you don't need to include it in `ReadList`. See my edit and try again without the path to the folder.

Comment: Also restart *Mathematica* and try again. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much; it works perfectly.

Comment: @Arash. Glad I could help.